# Looking to Improve My C# Coding Structure

Tags: c#, code-structure

I am a self taught programmer and i'm looking to improve my style.

I've been writing programs using the Autodesk Revit API and i've descided to take it a step further and started writing windows forms applications to help with my day-to day tasks. The Program is written in C#.

See here for my Github Repo for the current code: [Shear Interlock Program](https://github.com/pccrew/ShearInterlock)

My main focus of this program was the Units and the Parameter Classes. My use of static classes is excessive, but i found it was the only way to keep my implementation clean. I'm about to try to add a "print calculations and results to pdf" function, but i want to clean this up first.

Thank you to anyone who can lend a hand.

Comment: If you are looking of for a code review of your program I don't think this is the right forum for you. If you have a specific question please change your post accordingly.

Comment: Goto CodeReviews.StackExchange.com, closing this.

Comment: Need option to move questions to CodeReview

Comment: I see what you mean with all the statics, you could/should use Const's for much of the properties. Otherwise it's fine. One tip, you don't need to store the Obj\ and Debug\ folders in source control, you use products like Artifactory for binaries.

Comment: The static classes in Units are good as Singletons.

Comment: thanks guys, appologies for posting this in the wrong area. will move to CodeReviews.StackExchange.com

Comment: Static is okay for stuff like Function Collections, Singelton/Factory pattern, Extension Methods. It is only once they provide or contain data in any way that things become problematic. A good middle ground I found is creating a class that must be instantiated, but assign the instance to a static field - maybe even in a static class. It gives the reachability fo static, without any of the downsides at some class creation overhead.

Comment: interesting. I'll look into moving this to a singleton pattern.

Comment: You should have a look at https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet